# Consolidating spaces between words?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I'm trying to figure out how to consolidate spacing between words. How do I do this?

I will give an example:

```
"January     of    2002    while    
working as a clerk in 
the mailroom. 
Apparently, she was 
carrying some trays
 weighing approximately 17 pounds. Apparently, 
she had sustained injuries to her back. She got reinjured on 1/25/02 while picking a mail meter."
```

I need it to look like this:

```
"January of 2002 while working as a clerk in the mailroom. Apparently, she was carrying some trays weighing approximately 17 pounds. Apparently, she had sustained injuries to her back. She got reinjured on 1/25/02 while picking a mail meter."
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Download [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/).
2. Open your text file with it and go to *Edit* --> *Blank Operations* --> *Remove unnecessary Blank and EOL*. Your text will have its excess line breaks removed.
3. Now your text will only contain excess blank spaces which you can get rid of easily by doing the following in Notepad++: *Search* --> *Replace*. In the *Find what* box enter two blanks like "  " (without quotes). In the *Replace with* box use a single blank " " (without quotes). Press *Replace all*.
4. Repeat step 3 a couple of times and your text will end up without excess blank spaces.

Comment: Wouldn't copying content from a Word document into NotePad cause all formating to be lost?

Comment: Yes it would, but the question doesn't contain anything about which text format we're talking about. The sample text rather looks like we're talking about text dumps. Why would someone write a Word document in such a fashion? A text dump on the other hand would basically have no formatting since it seems to have been lost already. If it wasn't then there would probably be no need to ask the question ;)